# How to add data to elements created in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

My question is simple, how do I insert data,using XSLT, into an element tag that I created in my XSLT?

For Example I used this to create my element:

```
<xsl:template match="VEHICLE">
  <xsl:element name="{@STATUS}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

XML structure: (input)

```
<cars>
  <VEHICLE>
    <MODEL>FORD</MODEL>
    //other elements here
  </VEHICLE>
  <VEHICLE>
    <MODEL>DODGE</MODEL>
    //other elements here
  </VEHICLE>    
</cars>
```

(Desired Output)

```
 <cars>
      <VEHICLE>
        <MODEL>FORD</MODEL>
        <STATUS>SOLD</STATUS>
        //other elements here
      </VEHICLE>
      <VEHICLE>
        <MODEL>DODGE</MODEL>
        <STATUS>AVAILABLE</STATUS>
        //other elements here
      </VEHICLE>
</cars>
```

Comment: Please make clear how your input output xml will/should look like. I assume the xml above is your output and the value of @STATUS is MODEL. But than your "other elements" is not included in the new element.

Comment: FYI, in the XML input, the opening `<cars>` tag doesn't match the closing `</car>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an element `<foo/>` like this:

```
<xsl:template match="VEHICLE">
  <xsl:element name="{@STATUS}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <foo/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: To be honest I don't really understand what you mean. Could you please explain further?

Comment: That will add `<foo/>` to your output. Maybe if you show what output you want, I could give you a more precise answer.

Comment: Ok, I can definitely do that. By adding <foo/> are you referring to a new element or to the data inside the element? I hope that is helpful to clarify my question.  I just updated to give my output, does that help?

Comment: Yes `<foo/>` creates a new element in the result.

Answer (score 0):

In your input document I've changed `//other elements here` to `<!--//other elements here-->` but apart from that, this transform gives the result you want;

**Input**

```
<cars>
  <VEHICLE>
    <MODEL>FORD</MODEL>
    <!--//other elements here-->
  </VEHICLE>
  <VEHICLE>
    <MODEL>DODGE</MODEL>
    <!--//other elements here-->
  </VEHICLE>    
</cars>
```

**Transform**

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="cars">
    <cars>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </cars>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="VEHICLE">
    <VEHICLE>
      <xsl:if test="MODEL = 'FORD'">
        <STATUS>SOLD</STATUS>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="MODEL = 'DODGE'">
        <STATUS>AVAILABLE</STATUS>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    </VEHICLE>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Result**

```
<cars>
  <VEHICLE>
    <STATUS>SOLD</STATUS>
    <MODEL>FORD</MODEL>
    <!--//other elements here-->
  </VEHICLE>
  <VEHICLE>
    <STATUS>AVAILABLE</STATUS>
    <MODEL>DODGE</MODEL>
    <!--//other elements here -->
  </VEHICLE>
</cars>
```